# How to set imageButtons to VISIBLE at onResume() method?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with some imageButtons in it. After I click on them i use setVisible(View.INVISIBLE); to have them gone. Now, when a user enter correct answer, a popup screen pops up with some info and OK button. I need to set all my imageButtons to be invisible  when that popup window close. I tried to make some method:

```
private void removeImages(){
        b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

and then call it onResume:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        removeImages();

    }
```

But it does not work, it removes all my imageButtons as soon as I start that activity. How to do that after my popup windows closes, after I press OK button on that popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png0), `onResume()` is called before the `Actviivty` is in the foreground. You have a couple different options. You can use `startActviityForResult()` when you click an `ImageButton`and check that value in `onActivityResult()` to set the `Views` how you wish. Or you could save a value in `SharedPreferences` to tell the `Activity` which `Views` to set invisible/visible in `onResume()`

Comment: I have 36 imageButtons so using startActivityForResult() sounds complicated and a lot of code. How to do the SharedPreferences thing?

Comment: I just meant to use `startActivityForResult()` to return a value which tells `onResume()` to run `removeImages()`. This way it won't happen when `onResume()` is called on first creation of the `Activity`

Comment: And how to do that? I know how to return values like int using startActivityForResult() but I don't know how to return value which tells onResume() to run removeImages()?

Comment: You actually don't even need to do that. If you only want to remove those images then you just call that method in `onActivityResult()`. It doesn't need to be in `onResume()`

Comment: I just need to remove them. I will try that.

Comment: What should I put as second parameter in startActivityForResult()? If I return some int value I place something like Intent i = new Intent(FirstClass.this, Popup.class); and startActivityForResult(i, someIntVariable);

Comment: I declare a constant at the class level like, `static final int MY_REQUEST = 0;` then use that constant. This has to be there but is really just used if you have more than one `Actviity` sending data back here

Comment: Can I still use i.putExtra stuff, cause I need it?

Comment: You sure can. The only difference is that this `Activity` is awaiting a response from the next `Activity` when you call `setResult()`

Comment: I have similar problem to this. Can you check it out, maybe I can use onResult also for that? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879945/how-to-save-points-after-popup-close-and-avoid-repetition-from-sqlite)

Comment: You said I can send stuff using i.putExtra, but I can't send anything.

Comment: Yes I did something wrong. I didn't see that I first called startActivityForResult and after that i.putExtra. When I switch their places everything worked perfectly. :)